# Use StartActivity in OnPostExecute()

Tags: java, android, asynchronous, android-activity

I know that this question was already write, and it's that why , i post my question because it's very strange...
I just want to go to an other activity since OnPostExecute() of my AsyncTask. 
So i saw that this line works :

```
this.context.startActivity(new Intent(this.context, com.ListCrossingPoint.ListCrossingPoint.class));
```

Where  **this.context** is the context of the start activity , which is in the constructor of the asyntask and **com.ListCrossingPoint.ListCrossingPoint.class** is the class reach, which is in other package.

And thinking that it's will work well , i have this error :

```
03-11 14:59:22.304: E/AndroidRuntime(1041): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
03-11 14:59:22.304: E/AndroidRuntime(1041): android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: Unable to find explicit activity class {com.main/com.ListCrossingPoint.ListCrossingPoint}; 
                      have you declared this activity in your AndroidManifest.xml?
03-11 14:59:22.304: E/AndroidRuntime(1041): at android.app.Instrumentation.checkStartActivityResult(Instrumentation.java:1541)
03-11 14:59:22.304: E/AndroidRuntime(1041): at android.app.Instrumentation.execStartActivity(Instrumentation.java:1416)
...
```

So , i went to see if my activity was declare and , yess, it declared, so i don't understand ..

```
   <activity android:name="com.listcrossingpoint.ListCrossingPoint"     android:label="@string/menu_point_list" 
android:configChanges="orientation" android:screenOrientation="landscape" />
```

Comment: have you defined `com.ListCrossingPoint.ListCrossingPoint` this Activity in AndroidManifest.xml?

Comment: Change it to `this.context.startActivity(new Intent(this.context, ListCrossingPoint.class));`

Comment: @i.n.e.f : i defined yes , there are my code .

Comment: @codeMagic i changed and it's the same problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i resolved my problem. I renamed the package com.listpoint , like this , there is no ambiguity and i verify all reference and it's work. Thank everybody =)

Answer (score 1):

you have a typo in

```
 com.ListCrossingPoint.ListCrossingPoint.class
```

that mismatch with the entry in the Manifest. It should be

```
 com.listCrossingPoint.ListCrossingPoint.class
```

you have the capital `L` in the `Intent` constructor, but it is lower case in the `AndroidManifest.xml`

Comment: i am obliged to put lowercase otherwise , i will put "$" instead of '.'

Answer (score 0):

I assume it is due to the wrong spelling:

in `startActivity()` you call

```
"com.ListCrossingPoint.ListCrossingPoint.class"
```

in the `Manifest` you have

```
"com.listcrossingpoint.ListCrossingPoint"
```

(upper and lower case L)

Answer (score 0):

Woohoo Its an issue of Spell Mistake. What you have defined in AndroidManifest.xml is

```
<activity android:name="com.listcrossingpoint.ListCrossingPoint"     android:label="@string/menu_point_list" 
android:configChanges="orientation" android:screenOrientation="landscape" />
```

And you are calling

```
this.context.startActivity(new Intent(this.context,   com.ListCrossingPoint.ListCrossingPoint.class));
```

this in Intent. Its a problem of Package Name.

Change this **ListCrossingPoint** to **listcrossingpoint**.

Comment: my package name is : com.ListCrossingPoint and my class name is : ListCrossingPoint.java , but in the manifest , the name before class should be write in lowercase , and i pet **listcrossingpoint** and eclipse don't find the package

Answer (score 0):

Can you rename your package to listcrossingpoint with lowercase?, you mustn't use uppercase to package names.

You can use refactor/rename in eclipse to do it. (Alt+Shift+R)

Comment: i going to do this and i come back , think it's will be better effectively